# Getting the text from a searchview widget in a fragment

Tags: android

I am working on an Android app that has a navigation drawer, MainActivity and six fragments. Each navigation drawer item opens a different fragment.
On MainActivity I have included a searchview widget to use it as search box:

MainActivity:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        // Retrieve the SearchView and plug it into SearchManager
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

HomeFragment

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Do something that differs the Activity's menu here
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_search:

                Log.d("SEARCH", "pulsado search" );
                return false;


            default:
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

It is now working, I mean, when the search icon is clicked an edittext is shown.
How can I get the text inserted in this edittext to work with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think your looking below piece of code

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**Best Approach.**

> Please use interfacing mechanism for the fragments.Based on current
>   fragment shown to user call callback method to notify fragment that
>   search text changed.
>   [sample link](http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/)

**Simple Approach.**

> Provide one public method all the fragments.Based on current
>   fragment shown to user call method to notify fragment that
>   search text changed.

**Worst Approach.**

> use "getActivity" inside all the fragments then "findViewById", and use "setOnQueryTextListener". Make sure your having proper reference.

Comment: I guess you are right, but I need to use the searchView inside the fragment, not in the activity

Comment: I will try your last proposal

Comment: could you help me further? I am not able to understand your Best Approach

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    // Inflate menu to add items to action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}
```

ResultActivity.class

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        //use the query to search
    }
    }
    }
```

activity_result.xml, the layout for search results.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#ff3dc0ff">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/search_result" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In Manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".SearchResultsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCompatTheme">

        <!-- to identify this activity as "searchable" -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

Add the following searchable.xml file in folder “res/xml”.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

You may try the above code it will work

Comment: and what do I need to change in the fragment to get the editext content?

Comment: thank you, but your proposal. My issue is that I have already implemented all the search process using a normal edittext. What I need, if possible, is to get the search string from the searchview in the toolbar

Comment: https://www.viralandroid.com/2016/03/implementing-searchview-in-android-actionbar.html